# Overfitting ANN (UNSW-NB15 dataset)

Tags: deep-learning

My ANN is overfitting.

I cleaned up some values (e.g. 'is_ftp_login' had a different value then 0 or 1), dropped the highly correlated values from both test and train sets, removed unnecesarry columns ('attack_cat', 'id', 'response_body_len', 'spkts', 'dpkts', 'ct_flw_http_mthd', 'is_ftp_login'), onehotenconded the columns 'service', 'proto' and 'state' and get rid of them from both test and train sets, and finally used StandardScaler on train and test sets.

My ANN looks like:

---

```
model_ann = Sequential()
model_ann.add(Dense(64,activation='relu',input_dim=176))noduri
model_ann.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_ann.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model_ann.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_ann.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model_ann.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model_ann.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data = (x_test, y_test), batch_size=32, epochs=25)
model_ann.summary()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCMl3.png)

Thank you for the help! Tell me if I need to provide more information.